# Using worksheet 2 in a VB function stored in worksheet 1

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I wanted to compare the values of 2 columns in 2 different sheets and in case of equal values then the corresponding cell in the first sheet will take the same value in the corresponding cell in the second sheet. So I used a loop function, but the problem is that I cannot define and use the second sheet in the function in the first sheet.

I will appreciate guiding me to solving this problem.

You will find below the function I want to use:

```
Sub Test_V01()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Dim Bouira As Excel.Worksheet

    For j = 3 To 100
        For i = 3 To 120
            If Cells(j, 3) = Bouira!Cells(i, 30) Then 
                Cells(j, 12) = Bouira!Cells(i, 31)
            End If
        Next i                 
    Next j

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Replace `Cells(j, 3)` and `Cells(j, 12)` with `Me.Cells(j, 3)` and `Me.Cells(j, 12)` respectively to make sure the cells from this sheet are always used, and not the cells from the active sheet.
2. Replace `Bouira!Cells` with `Bouira.Cells`. There is no collection in the sheet an element of which would have the literal value of `Cells`.
3. Assign a reference to `Bouira` before entering the loop:

   ```
   Set Bouira = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet name")
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This will set reference to worksheet `Bouira`:

```
Sub Test_V01()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, Bouira As Worksheet

    Set Bouira = Worksheets("Bouira")

    For j = 3 To 100
        For i = 3 To 120
            If Cells(j, 3) = Bouira.Cells(i, 30) Then
                Cells(j, 12) = Bouira.Cells(i, 31)
            End If
        Next i
    Next j

End Sub
```